# ascii character url fails to redirect page

Tags: php, facebook, url, ascii

I build some Facebook-login for my website. I send this parameter to Facebook api as so

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclient_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.fr%2Fmydir%2Findex.php%253Fpage%253Dlogin&state=mystate&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions
```

Everything goes well until the redirection process :

```
http://mysite.fr/mydir/index.php%3Fpage%3Dlogin?code=somecopde
```

I get this error message

```
The requested URL /mydir/index.php?page=login was not found on this server.
```

But everything goes normal if I replace `%3F` by `?` in `redirect_uri` to

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.fr%2Fmydir%2Findex.php?page%253Dlogin&state=mystate&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions
```

Why is it so, How can I adjust this ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you double url encodes your get parameters

See:

```
myclient_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.fr%2Fmydir%2Findex.php%253Fpage%253Dlogin&state=mystate&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions
```

Lets try url decode you url:
http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.fr%2Fmydir%2Findex.php%253Fpage%253Dlogin&state=mystate&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions

First time:
http://mysite.fr/mydir/index.php%3Fpage%3Dlogin&state=mystate&scope=email,publish_actions

You can see that the ? is still encoded to %3F and your = is still encoded to %3D

to fix this you should not urlencode you url twice. I need to know more about your implementation if this information is not enough.